# How to get more specific error message when loading major mode with syntax errors

Tags: error

When I load my custom major mode, Emacs reports an error in the minibuffer about unescaped character literals, but it doesn't say where. I cannot even copy the error message here, since it disappears when my mouse pointer comes near.

So how can I get a more verbose and less ephemeral error message? Or is there a way to perform a syntax check on a buffer with elisp?

Comment: Try:  `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`  See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Error-Debugging.html

Comment: Thanks, but enabling that didn't really do anything when doing M-x load-library or evaluating (load-library "my-mode") in the scratch buffer.

Comment: Check the `*Messages*` buffer: that might contain the error message that disappears.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that buffer lists all errors (still no line information, though). I'm still quiet inexperienced in elisp programming.

Comment: Does it show the `point` at which the error is encountered? If  it does show it (let's say it shows `error ... at point 631`), then put your cursor at the beginning of the `my-mode.el` buffer and say `C-u 630 C-f`: you'll then be at point 631 of the buffer and presumably at the location of the error. Alternatively, `C-u 631 M-x goto-char` will go to the right place. Line information cannot be determined without some calculation, so it is not often used in emacs itself (although certain commands like `grep` and `compile` do use line numbers in their results).

Comment: NickD, thanks for your explanation! In the case I mentioned here, the error message included no position information, but your description will be helpful for future errors.